# javame: is it possible to disable AGC / VAD when recording using the microphone?

Tags: audio, java-me, audio-recording

We are developing an application which takes audio from the microphone and does some analysis. We found during the analysis, that [AGC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control) is implemented on the microphone subsystem. Also I have heard that [VAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) is used.

1. Are there any other post processing done on the audio(PCM) before it is delivered to the application?
2. Is it possible for the application to disable the AGC and VAD post processing? Is it possible in JavaME or using some proprietary API, such as Nokia/Samsung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answers to my own questions:

1. Unknown.
2. Impossible in JavaME. If you are working on Symbian/S60
   devices, you could check if Qt or Symbian C++ has such capability. For example, I found the following info on the web, but did not check it: "There is an API called SetGain/GetMaxGain in CMdaAudioInputStream, but in S60 phones the range is between 1-1, so not very useful using this API. But you can use CVoIPAudioUplinkStream which allows you to dynamically control the audio gain and other codec properties". Try if you are interested in...